# Counting Number of Appearances with a Condition

Tags: spss

I'm trying to count the number of times an email appears in my data.
I'm currently using this code:

```
AGGREGATE /OUTFILE=* MODE=ADDVARIABLES /BREAK=Email 
/Number=N.
```

This works fine but is missing one condition that I need.

I have another variable: Week (numeric) with options 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6.

I only want SPSS to count the emails if they appear in week 6 at some point.

So for instance:

```
  Email            Week         N
jane@aol.com         6          2
bill@gmail.com       3          
bill@gmail.com       4         
sarah@hotmail.com    6          1
jane@aol.com         4          2
```

So as you can see, because jane@aol.com appeared in Week 6 at least once, then I want it to count the rest of the appearances of her email in the file (including the ones not in week 6). 
But Bill, he appears in the file twice, but I never want to count him because neither instance was in Week 6.

How can I edit my syntax to accomplish this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, re-creating your example data:

```
data list list/email(a50) week(f1).
begin data
"jane@aol.com" 6
"bill@gmail.com" 3
"bill@gmail.com" 4
"sarah@hotmail.com" 6
"jane@aol.com" 4
end data.
```

Now run this:

```
* Identifying emails that had week 6 at least once:  .
if week=6 has6=1.
aggregate out=* mode=addvariables overwrite=yes/break=email /has6=max(has6).
* now to count occurences.
aggregate out=* mode=addvariables /break=email /n=sum(has6).
```